# How to separate between code and data in column settings for angular material table

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-table

```
 columns = [
        {
          columnDef: 'position',
          header: 'No.',
          cell: (element: PeriodicElement) => `${element.position}`,
          numberFilter: true,
          footer: true,
          footerValue: 'Total',
        },
        {
          columnDef: 'name',
          header: 'Name',
          cell: (element: PeriodicElement) => `${element.name}`, //cell settings
          stringFilter: true, //filter for strings
          filterList: ELEMENT_DATA.map((x) => x.name), //filter values
          footer: false,
        }
]
```

Given settings of columns for angular material tables. I want to create a generic component and import columns as an array of data from another file or even database.
However, I have there some callings to functions and code. Any idea how to resolve it, i.e. to import data to component with table and use functions locally?

Comment: Can you please explain it to further more ? Thank You.

Comment: @GRD I want to pass normal variables, not something like ELEMENT_DATA.map((x) => x.name), or (element: PeriodicElement) => `${element.position}`,. Then I can pass column settings as an array of objects and keep my data outside the component itself